# Authentication using a nonce

Tags: public-key, authentication, nonce

For an authentication problem imagine the following scenario with two devices:

- 1 server
- 1 client.

The client starts a conversation with the server and sends him his public key. All public keys in this scenario are signed by a CA.
The server validates the public key and sends his signed public key to the client together with a random nonce, which is encrypted with the public key of the client.
The client decrypts the nonce message with its private key, re-encrypts the nonce with the public key of the server and sends this message back to the server.
The server decrypts the nonce with his private key and checks if the nonce is the same as before.

The server then knows that he indeed communicated with the correct client (the one with the proper private key) and can authenticate the client.

**My question here:** Is this a valid and secure authentication protocol? If not, how could one improve it?

I googled a bit, but "authentication using nonce" or "asymetric nonce authentication" could not bring up proper answers for me.

I have the feeling that this protocol is flawed.
And I see the problem of a replay attack, because of the probability that the server generates the same nonce twice.
But if the nonce is random number between a large enough interval, this probability can be decreased. In addition to this, the encrypted nonce message is only identical if the same nonce was send to the same client twice (which makes this even more unlikely to happen).

Comment: Replay: you can mitigate it with a very large nonce, e.g. 64 bits are enough. The problem could be a reflection attack since you are encrypting the same quantity. Further, there is no MITM since the public keys are authenticated by an authority.

Comment: "In addition to this, the encrypted nonce message is only identical if the same nonce was send to the same client twice"; actually, any public key encryption algorithm will be randomized; and hence even if the server happen to pick the same nonce twice, the encrypted messages will be different.

Comment: @poncho exactly, but in general I discourage to do that (e.g. a switching to a symmetric algorithm with a key generated by DH).